# I don't understand this method

Tags: ruby

I'm a beginner in Ruby and I don't understand what this code is doing, could you explain it to me, please?

```
def a(n)
  s = 0
  for i in 0..n-1
    s += i
  end
  s
end
```

Comment: Sums the numbers from 0 to n.

Comment: And I'd argue it's not idiomatic.

Comment: @DaveNewton, consider the context.

Comment: @ndn I did. Same argument, though; there's no point in pretending you wouldn't normally see something like `(0..n).reduce(0) etc` IRL. It's a comment intending to inform, not to (a) imply it's intrinsically wrong or (b) denigrate the OP.

Comment: This example isn't idiomatic Ruby code even if it is syntactically valid. Ruby hardly ever uses the `for` construct, iterators are more flexible. `n.times do |i|` is how this is normally expressed.

Comment: In the future, it is helpful to be specific about what you don't understand in particular. Try to talk yourself through the method step by step and see which part in particular is confusing. For example, a non-ruby person may be confused by what the line `for i in 0..n-1` is doing but still understand before that you are declaring a variable `s = 0`. This process is useful for examining code in any language.

Comment: @DaveNewton, he obviously isn't going to start using Ruby on live projects tomorrow. Would you not agree that a person that doesn't understand what loops are should first learn the basics? And that *"iteration with `for` is not idiomatic, use higher level functions like `reduce`"* is only going to confuse them further?

Comment: @ndn *sigh* I have no way of knowing if it would confuse them further. `each`, as mentioned by tadman, *is* the basics in Ruby. `reduce` isn't far behind, and I'd argue that even with the extra cognitive hurdle, it's a lot more useful to (a) teach idiomatic Ruby, and (b) introduce the more functional aspects of it sooner than later. (I haven't found things like `reduce` very difficult to teach anyway, but YMMV.)

Comment: @DaveNewton, there is an argument to be made about bottom up and top down learning of programming. But my mileage definitely varies. Just last week I tried to explain to a person with very little programming experience what map, filter and reduce are (granted in JS, where the syntax is a little more cumbersome). I tried to make it as simple as possible, even used this [tweet](https://twitter.com/steveluscher/status/741089564329054208). Their position in the end was that "they think they understood how that worked, but wouldn't be able to use it on their own". And they preferred the `for` alt.

Comment: @ndn I don't want to know what happens after pop corn and before the egg with your reduce example.

Comment: @ndn Then I'd be wary. `for` loops are uncommon in Ruby, "preferred" or not, in favor of 'each'. Map, filter, and reduce are trivially explained with accumulators created outside `each` and simple conditionals inside the block.

Comment: @DaveNewton this is another thing I did. And a few other ways of thinking about it, and a lot more examples. Their problem is conceptual. I'm not sure if you are too disconnected with the way of thinking of an everyday person making their first steps in programming or if this is another of my failures in trying to explain something.

Comment: @ndn I train and mentor new developers, and have for almost 30 years--so I suspect the latter ;) But seriously: I readily admit that some folks aren't "naturals", but I've taught both kids and adults both the concept and code, using a variety of languages, for (what seems like) a really long time, and so far it's never taken more than a day, although sometimes it requires some one-on-one time.

Answer (score 4):

`def` defines a method. Methods can be used to run the same code on different values. For example, lets say you wanted to get the square of a number:

```
def square(n)
  n * n
end
```

Now I can do that with different values and I don't have to repeat `n * n`:

```
square(1) # => 1
square(2) # => 4
square(3) # => 9
```

---

`=` is an assignment.

`s = 0` basically says, behind the name `s`, there is now a *zero*.

---

`0..n-1` - constructs a range that holds all numbers between `0` and `n - 1`. For example:

```
puts (0..3).to_a
  # 0
  # 1
  # 2
  # 3
```

`for` assigns `i` each consecutive value of the range. It loops through all values. So first `i` is `0`, then `1`, then ... `n - 1`.

---

`s += i` is a shorthand for `s = s + i`. In other words, increments the existing value of `s` by `i` on each iteration.

---

The `s` at the end just says that the method (remember the thing we opened with `def`) will give you back the value of `s`. In other words - the sum we accumulated so far.

---

There is your programming lesson in 5 minutes.

Comment: Good job. As a kid, I remember seing `n = n+1` and thinking, `Wait, what? That's not possible!`

Answer (score 2):

This example isn't idiomatic Ruby code even if it is syntactically valid. Ruby hardly ever uses the `for` construct, iterators are more flexible. This might seem strange if you come from another language background where `for` is the backbone of many programs.

In any case, the program breaks down to this:

```
# Define a method called a which takes an argument n
def a(n)
  # Assign 0 to the local variable s
  s = 0

  # For each value i in the range 0 through n minus one...
  for i in 0..n-1
    # ...add that value to s.
    s += i
  end

  # The result of this method is s, the sum of those values.
  s
end
```

The more Ruby way of expressing this is to use `times`:

```
def a(n)
  s = 0

  # Repeat this block n times, and in each iteration i will represent
  # a value in the range 0 to n-1 in order.
  n.times do |i|
    s += i
  end

  s
end
```

That's just addressing the `for` issue. Already the code is more readable, mind you, where it's `n.times` *do something*. The `do ... end` block represents a chunk of code that's used for each iteration. Ruby blocks might be a little bewildering at first but understanding them is absolutely essential to being effective in Ruby.

Taking this one step further:

```
def a(n)
  # For each element i in the range 0 to n-1...
  (0..n-1).reduce |sum, i|
    # ...add i to the sum and use that as the sum in the next round.
    sum + i
  end
end
```

The `reduce` method is one of the simple tools in Ruby that's quite potent if used effectively. It allows you to quickly spin through lists of things and compact them down to a single value, hence the name. It's also known as `inject` which is just an alias for the same thing.

You can also use short-hand for this:

```
def a(n)
  # For each element in the range 0 to n-1, combine them with +
  # and return that as the result of this method.
  (0..n-1).reduce(&:+)
end
```

Where here `&:+` is shorthand for `{ |a,b| a + b }`, just as `&:x` would be short for `{ |a,b| a.x(b) }`.

Answer (score 1):

The method **a(n)** calculates the sums of the first **n** natural numbers.

**Example**:
when n=4, then s = 0+1+2+3 = 6

Answer (score 1):

As you are a beginner in Ruby, let's start from the small slices.

`0..n-1` => [0, n-1]. E.g. `0..3` => 0, 1, 2, 3 => [0, 3]

`for i in 0.. n-1` => this is a for loop. `i` traverses [0, n-1].

`s += i` is same as `s = s + i`

So. Method `a(n)` initializes `s = 0` then in the for loop i traverse [0, n - 1] and `s = s + i`

At the end of this method there is an `s`. Ruby omits key words `return`. so you can see it as `return s`

```
def a(n)
  s = 0
  for i in 0..n-1
    s += i
  end
  s
end
```

is same as

```
def a(n)
  s = 0
  for i in 0..n-1
    s = s + i
  end
  return s
end
```

`a(4)` = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 6

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go symbol by symbol!

```
def a(n)
```

This is the start of a function `def`inition, and you're defining the function `a` that takes a single parameter, `n` - all typical software stuff. Notably, you can `def`ine a function on other things, too:

```
foo = "foo"
def foo.bar
  "bar"
end
foo.bar() # "bar"
"foo".bar # NoMethodError
```

Next line:

```
  s = 0
```

In this line, you're both declaring the variable `s`, and setting it's initial value to `0`. Also typical programming stuff.

Notably, the value of the entire *expression*; `s = 0`, is the value of s after the assignment:

```
s = 0
r = t = s += 1 # You can think: r = (t = (s += 1) )
# r and t are now 1
```

Next line:

```
  for i in 0..n-1
```

This is starting a loop; specifically a `for ... in ...` loop. This one a little harder to unpack, but the entire statement is basically: "for each integer between `0` and `n-1`, assign that number to `i` and then do something". In fact, in Ruby, another way to write this line is:

```
(0..n-1).each do |i|
```

This line and your line are exactly the same.

For single line loops, you can use `{` and `}` instead of `do` and `end`:

```
(0..n-1).each{|i| s += i }
```

This line and your `for` loop are exactly the same.

`(0..n-1)` is a `range`. Ranges are super fun! You can use a lot of things to make up a range, particularly, time:

```
(Time.now..Time.new(2017, 1, 1)) # Now, until Jan 1st in 2017
```

You can also change the "step size", so that instead of every integer, it's, say, every 1/10:

```
(0..5).step(0.1).to_a # [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, ...]
```

Also, you can make the range exclude the last value:

```
(0..5).to_a # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
(0...5).to_a # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Next line!

```
s += i
```

Usually read aloud a "plus-equals". It's literally the same as: `s = s + 1`. AFAIK, almost every operator in Ruby can be paired up this way:

```
s = 5
s -= 2 # 3
s *= 4 # 12
s /= 2 # 6
s %= 4 # 2
# etc
```

Final lines (we'll take these as a group):

```
  end
  s
end
```

The "blocks" (groups of code) that are started by `def` and `for` need to be `end`ed, that's what you're doing here.

But also!

Everything in Ruby has a value. Every expression has a value (including assignment, as you saw with line 2), and every block of code.  **The default value of a block is the value of the last expression in that block**.

For your function, the last expression is simply `s`, and so the value of the expression is the value of `s`, after all is said and done. This is literally the same as:

```
  return s
end
```

For the loop, it's weirder - it ends up being the evaluated range.

This example may make it clearer:

```
n = 5
s = 0
x = for i in (0..n-1)
  s += i
end
# x is (0..4)
```

To recap, another way to write you function is:

```
def a(n)
  s = 0
  (0..n-1).each{ |i| s = s + i }
  return s
end
```

Questions?